# Speed up Test-Connection before Foreach

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach

I made a script to check if users desktop folder are under the cuota limitation, if they're under the cuota limitation the backup to the server will be done correctly.

each user have his computer, so source CSV looks like:

```
pc1,user1
pc2,user2
pc800,user800
```

Some computers are Windows Xp and some W7, and the paths can be different 'cause of that I'm using Test-Path

```
W7 = C:\users\$user\desktop
XP = C:\document and settings\$user\desktop
```

But Test-Path is SUPER SLOW and I started to use a Test-Connection -count 1 before each Test-path

Anyway, the script still SLOW, in each "bad ping test" I lose lot of time.

CODE:

```
$csvLocation = '~\desktop\soourceReport.csv'
$csv = import-csv $csvLocation -Header PCName, User

$OuputReport = '~\desktop\newReport.csv'

# info:
# "209715200" Bytes = 200 MB

$cuota = "209715200"
$cuotaTranslate = "$($cuota / 1MB) MB"
Write-Host "Cuota is set to $cuotaTranslate"

$count=1

foreach($item in $csv)
{
    write-host "$count# Revisando" $item.User "en" $item.PCName "..." #For debug

    if (Test-Connection -Quiet -count 1 -computer $($item.PCname)){

        $w7path = "\\$($item.PCname)\c$\users\$($item.User)\desktop"
        #echo $w7path #debug

        $xpPath = "\\$($item.PCname)\c$\Documents and Settings\$($item.User)\Escritorio"
        #echo $xp #debug

                if(Test-Path $W7path){

                    $desktopSize = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -force $w7path | Measure-Object -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" -property length -sum) 

                    write-host -ForegroundColor Green "access succeed"

                        if($($desktopSize.sum) -gt $cuota){


                            $newLine =  "{0},{1},{2}" -f $($item.PCname),$($item.User),"$("{0:N0}" -f $($desktopSize.sum / 1MB)) MB"
                            $newLine |  add-content $outputReport

                             Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "cuota exceeded! -- added"
                         }

                        else{
                         Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow  "cuota OK"
                        }


                }

                elseif(Test-Path $xpPath){

                    $desktopSize = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -force $xpPath | Measure-Object -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" -property length -sum) 

                    write-host -ForegroundColor Green "access succeed"

                        if($($desktopSize.sum) -gt $cuota){


                            $newLine =  "{0},{1},{2}" -f $($item.PCname),$($item.User),"$("{0:N0}" -f $($desktopSize.sum / 1MB)) MB"
                            $newLine |  add-content $outputReport

                             Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "cuota exceeded! -- added"
                         }

                        else{
                         Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow  "cuota OK"
                        }
                else{
                     write-host -ForegroundColor Red "Error! - bad path"
                }
    }

    else{
        write-host -ForegroundColor Red "Error! - no ping"
    }
    $count++
}
Write-Host -ForegroundColor green -BackgroundColor DarkGray "All done! new report stored in $report"
```

To improve it I stored all computers in a $list using another Foreach, before the firstly mentioned SLOW-Foreach loop.

```
foreach($pcs in $csv){

    $alivelist += @( $pcs.PCName )
}

Test-Connection -quiet -count 2 -computer $alivelist
```

Now, I don't now how to UPDATE or remove the rows ("dead" pc,user) from the SOURCE CSV before to enter into the second Foreach.

I need some of your "magic", or at least some ideas!

thanks

Comment: What can really speed things up is parallel processing. In PS 2.0 you can use background jobs for that and in 3.0 there are workflows. Check answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166998/powershell-script-running-slowly).

Comment: http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/gramsey/archive/2011/01/07/get-pingstatuslist-ps1-ping-hundreds-of-systems-quickly-using-the-start-job-command-in-powershell.aspx. Adding to @AlexanderObersht comment about background jobs. I've used this guys script before

Comment: I was looking for a fast ping sweeper and came across this question.  I settled on this script: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Fast-asynchronous-ping-IP-d0a5cf0e/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To speed up your script you need to run the checks in parallel (as others have already mentioned). Put your checks and the worker code in a scriptblock:

```
$sb = {
    Param($computer, $username)

    if (Test-Connection -Quiet -Count 2 $computer) { return }

    $w7path = "\\$computer\c$\users\$username\desktop"
    $xpPath = "\\$computer\c$\Documents and Settings\$username.TUITRA..."

    if (Test-Path $W7path) {
        #...
    } elseif (Test-Path $xpPath) {
        #...
    } else {
        #...
    }
}
```

Then run the scriptblock as parallel jobs:

```
$csv | ForEach-Object {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList $_.PCName, $_.User
}

# wait for completion
do {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
} while (Get-Job -State 'Running')

# cleanup
Get-Job | ForEach-Object {
    Receive-Job -Id $_.Id
    Remove-Job -Id $_.Id
} | Out-File $outputReport
```

Use a [queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18193195/1630171) if you need to limit the number of parallel jobs.

Comment: but now the output CSV is not working, error- is a nil path, I moved $Outputreport inside $sb... now the csv is partially created, stops saying that is being used by other process. No clue.

Comment: @pedaleo: You ran into a scoping issue. `$outputReport` inside the scriptblock is a different variable than `$outputReport` in the rest of your script. You need to pass the report path into the scriptblock via the `-ArgumentList` parameter if you want to use it there. However, that's not a good idea, because it creates other problems (concurrent file access for instance). Better remove `| Add-Content $outputReport` from the scriptblock and redirect the output on the Success output stream when you retrieve it via `Receive-Job`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

test-connection is weirdly fast with the -asjob parameter, pinging about 200 computers in 4 seconds:

```
$list = cat hp.txt
test-connection $list -AsJob ; job | receive-job -wait -AutoRemoveJob
```