# Custom-Ping Tweaking for catching Errors

Tags: powershell

I was editing a script and realized soon that i need to tweak my funtion.

I cant really tell how powershell gives back a result but i need to work with one of 3 joices

But it doesnt seem to work at all,
as the part with the "error" action doesnt work properly.

In further advance of the code i use this to check which Categorie it hits but this seems to be quite a bit random as i have a testing IP list set
where are all three types and the frist 254 request are only the "error" exception but it jumps around between those 3.

```
Function Custom-Ping {
    Param(
        [string]$Address
    )
    $ping = ping $Address /w 1 /n 1
    if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ping -Like "*expired*"))
    {
        $result = "Error"
    }
    elseif(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ping -Like "*(0% loss)*"))
    {
        $result = "hit"
    }
    else
    {
        $result = ""
    }
    return $result
}
```

The reason why I use the Custom Ping is to speed up the task as i tried to resolve over 8000 Ip requests in our local network.

The `Test-Connection 'SomeIP' -Count 1`works in my envrioment, but `Test-Connection 'SomeIP' -Count 1 -TimeoutSeconds 1` isnt working at all as i dont have the `-TimeoutSeconds` as option.

The Parralel workaround didnt worked for me as I didn't got it running in any matter.

Comment: Why are you trying to re-implement `Test-Connection`?

Comment: As the Test-Connection takes about 3-4 seconds if the request fails and the ping command with its alternates takes about 0.5seconds which you cant hanlde with Test-Connection, which ends up with a time diffrence of about 3 hourse+ in my example

Comment: `Test-Connection` has a `-TimeoutSeconds` parameter you can set to 1 and also a `-Count` parameter.. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-6#parameters). True, they are `Int32` parameters, so you can't do half-a-second, but isn't a timeout of one whole second not fast enough?

Comment: as i tried the `-TimeoutSeconds` it threw an error on me which i couldnt resolve the `-Count`part worked properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speed up Test-Connection before Foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442731/speed-up-test-connection-before-foreach)

Comment: It is less a duplicate as i need to differ between those 3 Options anyway, and the handle of the this post doesnt works on my script is I get constant errors as I have to less experince with this "solution".

Comment: you may want to check this out ... `([System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping]::new()).SendPingAsync()`.