# Slow Processing Script in Powershell, Worklfow first steps

Tags: powershell

as i was wondering why my script takes so long i was seachring on google and also here in stackoverflow.

But all that i could find any close to helpful was this one here, [Powershell Script Running Slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166998/powershell-script-running-slowly)

As I'm still pretty new to Powershell this is a little complicated to get through and take over to my script as i dont know how to handle those mentiond things anyway as i never heard of it before.

My Script is pretty easy and just gives me some Informations if there is something that returns an echo or not.

I wanted to "scan" our entire Network so I made an csv with out local Networks IP's and pass it to Powershell to "Ping" those.

But I realised that the "was not responing" part takes a long time to execute.

```
$list = Import-Csv -Path D:\ipcheck3.csv -UseCulture
$x=$list.IP
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
foreach ($y in $x)
{

    try
    {
        if(Test-Connection $y -Count 1 -quiet)
        {
            write-host "$y responded" 
            $y | Export-Csv -Path D:\PingSucceded.csv -Append
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "$y was not responding"
            $y | Export-Csv -Path D:\Pingfailed.csv -Append
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning "Other Error occured" 
    }

}
```

There are not only Windows Clients out there so WMI is not an option and I don't know how to achvie this otherwise

EDIT:

After the Workflow input this is my "Try Version"

```
workflow Test-IPrange
{
    Param
    (       
        $IPs
    )

    $tocheck= $IPs.IP

    foreach -parallel ($IP in $tocheck)
    {
        $pingsucceed = Test-Connection $IP -Count 1 -quiet

        if($pingsucceed -eq "True")
        {
            $IP | Export-Csv -Path D:\testj.csv -Append
        }
        else
        {
            $IP | Export-Csv -Path D:\testn.csv -Append
        }
    }
}

Test-IPrange -IPs $(Import-Csv -Path D:\ipcheck3.csv -UseCulture)
```

My Output of Workflow Try

```
#TYPE System.String
PSComputerName,"PSShowComputerName","PSSourceJobInstanceId","Length"
localhost,"True","4e208e38-f7c2-492f-9d81-6583a103c3ac","12"
localhost,"True","4e208e38-f7c2-492f-9d81-6583a103c3ac","12"
```

With the Help of @Fourat

i edited my code to this form

```
Function Custom-Ping {
    Param(
        [string]$Address
    )
    $ping = ping $Address /w 1 /n 1
    $result = ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ping -Like "*(0% Verlust)*")
    return $result
} 

$list = Import-Csv -Path D:\ipcheck3.csv -UseCulture
$x=$list.IP
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
foreach ($y in $x)
{

    try
    {
        if(Custom-Ping $y)
        {           
            Write-Host "$y responded"
            $y | Export-Csv -Path D:\PingsuccededV3.csv -Append
        }
        else
        {

            Write-Host "$y was not responding"
            $y | Export-Csv -Path D:\PingfailedV3.csv -Append
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning "Textline from CMD Command or other Error" 
    }

}
```

which works properly good and is faster

Comment: Can you add some numbers ?? How many IP you have in your file and how much time your script takes to process them ? Try increase/decrease the number of IPs and maybe give us an average of time per IP.

Comment: I've been there my self, and you do use a slow method.
What I did to speed it up a ton, was using Workflow in a foreatch -parallel setup.
It took a little time as workflow are just Powershell, but do convert the code to something else.

You can read about workflows here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/sma/overview-powershell-workflows?view=sc-sma-2019

Comment: What OS are you on?  `Test-NetConnection` is a very useful cmdlet on Win8.1+

Comment: @Fourat
I have about 4500 IP's to check
the avg on a suceed is 0.74 seconds
the avg on a fail is:  4.611 seconds

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'm on a win10 system with powershell 5

Comment: @Kevin I think you won't have much choice, 0.74 on average is a good result. Ping request are usually 0.05s however your average can be spoiled with one fail because of the timeout. I would suggest you use `-Parallel` with your foreach : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel?view=powershell-5.1 but it won't help much.

Comment: You can check this solution too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618904/how-to-use-multithreading-script/53620553#53620553

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your process time is spoiled by the timeouts. If all your IPs are in the local network, try to reduce the timeout (because the default value is 5 seconds).

If you have [Powershell 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-6) :

```
Test-Connection $y -Count 1 -quiet -TimeoutSeconds 1
```

If you don't, just use [ping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ping) :

```
ping 58.47.45.1 /w 1 /n 1
```

You can also use a parallel for each loop, but it won't help much if you have multiple fails :

```
ForEach -Parallel ($x in $y)
{
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

In order to handle `ping` results, you can use a function like this (I used the keyword 'perte' because my computer is in French) :

```
Function Custom-Ping {
    Param(
        [string]$Address
    )
    $ping = ping $Address /w 1 /n 1
    $result = ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ping -Like "*(perte 0%)*")
    return $result
}
```

Comment: i'm poorly on PW 5 and when i Try ping it will responde everytime with succeded as there was an ping but it failed

and with the workflow i'm trying to figure it out how it works

Comment: @Kevin, I added a function to handle `ping` results.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i now get all pings as false (i changed the word perte with our language)

Comment: I found the mistake here as the command is executed in another language.

Thank you for your help

Comment: @Kevin, you're welcome. Please mark my answer as the right answer if it solved your question.

Comment: I got one more question, as the output is now no psobject i get something like #TYPE System.String
Length
10
how can i convert this ?

Comment: @Kevin the output of `Custom-Ping` ?

Comment: yes as the cmd command only provides a string to powershell and no object,
does this mean i need to create a custom object and how to achive this in this scenario tho as i never made any Custom object and special not in such a scenario

Answer (score 1):

I've used Workflow to solve this issue my self. It's a few years ago I did it, so something better and newer is out there. But this works great for me...
I've ping over 2000 computers within a few Min...

```
workflow Test-ComputersConnection
{
Param
(
    # Param1 help description
    $Computernames#,

    # Param2 help description
    #        [int]
    #        $Param2
)

foreach -parallel ($ComputerName in $Computernames)
{
    $ConnectionTest = Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Count 1

    if ($ConnectionTest.Address -eq $ComputerName) {
        Write-Output $(Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computername" -Value $ComputerName -InputObject $ConnectionTest -PassThru )
        #Write-Verbose -Verbose -Message "[$($ComputerName)]: Replays on Ping."
    }
    Else {
        #Write-Verbose -Verbose -Message "[$($ComputerName)]: Do not replays on Ping."
    }
}
}

$OnlineNow0 = Test-ComputersConnection -Computernames $( Import-Csv -Path D:\ipcheck3.csv -UseCulture |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty name)
```

The code above is a quick edit of what I use... You will need to edit the $(Import ...) statement first, to make sure the PC name is being deliveret to the workflow.

I've just testet on my own computer and it gave me a reply...

Comment: thank you so far for the answer i'm trying to figure out how exactly to work with the workflow